# When should we implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

My main page contains view model properties and main page xaml elements are bound with view model properties by x:bind. Do i need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for main page?

If INotifyPropertyChanged is not implemented in mainpage there is no build issue. But updating bound properties sometimes throws run-time exception.

But when i implement INotifyPropertyChanged for main page everything works fine.

```
property VM::TheViewModel^ ViewModel
{
   VM::TheViewModel^ get()
   {
       return VM::AppData::ViewModel;
   }
}
```

The AppData class provides static view models

```
ref class AppData
    {
    public:
        static property VM::TheViewModel^ ViewModel
        {
            VM::TheViewModel^ get()
            {
                static VM::TheViewModel^ vm= ref new vm::TheViewModel();
                return vm;
            }
        }
    }
```

xaml data binding :

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyProperty}"
```

I am not sure why should i implement

> INotifyPropertyChanged

for main page. When i have the properties in the view model classes?

From the background thread I stop my timers. Navigate to a init page and then come back to the main page with some conditions. While switching back to mainpage by starting the timers and running the background thread the run-time exceptions occurs. It's not a regular scenario. Sometimes it's occurs sometimes it doesn't. But it happens.

```
OnSomeModelChange()
{
...
    if (notifyId == SessionPropertyNotifyType::Session)
        {
            StopTimers();
            AppData::ViewModelInfo->ClearErrors();
            auto rootFrame = dynamic_cast<Frame^>(Window::Current->Content);
            rootFrame->Navigate(TypeName(InitPage::typeid), nullptr, ref new Animation::SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo);
            Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(
                Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Low,
                ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]() { InitSessionAsync(); }, CallbackContext::Any)
            );
        }
...
}
```

Call Stack :
[image]

The exception :
Exception thrown: read access violation.

```
this->__this->**** was 0xDDDDDDDD.
```

Comment: I tested your code and didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged in main page, when I updated the binding property, it didn't throw the run-time exception, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to  test? In addition, about when to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, when your ViewModel property has been changed, you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your viewmodel and expose the PropertyChanged event to notify the UI bound to it to update its value.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT My view model properties continuously update from background thread. threads are created by timers. And it's managed/triggered from app class. From the background thread i am navigating to some other page and coming back to main page with some conditions. Please see the edit for the navigation from the background thread.

Comment: If you didn't use INotifyPropertyChanged, how can you update your value? And if you want to investigate the cause of the issue, please provide more detailed information, e.g. the name of the exception, the error code. And it's better to show which line of code is wrong and provide the related code.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I have shared the call stack. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the view models where the properties are but not in the mainpage cause mainpage do not have any properties which are bound to xaml element. It's not a regular issue so hard to share whole picture. But i can share as much as we need to go through it. I am already wasting your time sorry about it. Please see the edit. The exception is Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->__this->**** was 0xDDDDDDDD.

Comment: x:Bind uses OneTime binding by default. Try changing your binding to ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}" and try again. 

Also, updating properties from background thread using INotifyPropertyChanged will throw an expection in WinRT. You need to dispatch the request and execute it on the UI thread.

Comment: @BurakKaanKöse i think the default binding mode is oneway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.mode. dispatch is used when it's needed otherwise it throws marshaling error clearly.

Comment: It looks like a pointer reference problem, has the attribute been assigned correctly or you reference Null pointer?